# Is it possible to set Primary keys in the HUB database in Azure Data Sync?

Tags: azure, azure-data-sync

One of my tables in the HUB has a primary key that is causing records to be dropped in all the member databases. This Primary Key dynamically changes based on record updates.

I understand that Azure data sync uses these keys to track changes, but for the primary key that has dynamic data generated, it is dropping those records in the member database.

Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Data Sync, changing PK values is not supported, you need to delete the record and insert a new one.

Comment: This was my experience. Thank you for the confirmation.